# How to get url from 'link' element in Selenium IDE

Tags: url, selenium, hyperlink, ide

I want to get (and store to variable) url of one hyperlink (link) on the web page. Is it possible to get it in the Selenium IDE?

In my test I have to verify, if link exists, then store url from this link and use it later in the test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Although this question was originally asked for the IDE, I just came here through Google searching for the same answer for **Python**.

The one above gives

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'
```

because for Python it is

```
driver.find_element(By.xxx).get_attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 10):

```
driver.findElement(By.xxx).getAttribute('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply use [storeAttribute](https://web.archive.org/web/20110525081059/http://www.hexbytes.com/?paged=2#post-56).

I could be more explicit if you'd say whether you're using Selenese or some other language.

Comment: I am laughing. My answer got downvoted into the negative for being the only one relevant to the Selenium IDE. It is possible you have not heard of it. The original poster specifically asked in relation to the Selenium IDE, a plug-in that actually works in the version of Firefox that was current back then. (It still works in the Pale Moon browser.) You can see that the OP thanked me.